# Relative path: Unable to select correct relative path for accessing a config file

Tags: java, io, filesystems, relative-path

My Project structure is as below:

> MyModule  ->classes-->SerPkg--->myclass.class
>
> MyModule  ->src-->config--->config.properties
>
> MyModule  ->src-->SerPkg--->myclass.java

I am trying to access the `config.properties` file here with below code but I am getting File not found exception.

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream("../../src/config/config.properties");
```

I tried the below code to find out the current Dir and I found that the classes folder which have the class files is the current folder. I tried as below things :

```
 String current = new java.io.File( "." ).getCanonicalPath();
 System.out.println("Current dir:"+current);
 String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 System.out.println("Current dir using System:" +currentDir);
 System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
                    System.getProperty("user.dir")); 

  // all above cmds give "MyModule" as current dir
         System.out.println("Path:"+this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath());  

// above last cmd gives "classes" as current dir
```

I am unable to access the `config.properties` file from either class folder or MyModule folder as current dir.

Comment: Why don't you just access it as a classpath resource?

Comment: Probably `new FileInputStream("../src/config/config.properties");`? If you're in `classes`, then you should go only one folder up.

Comment: @TagirValeev ..tried this didnt worked

Comment: @fge ...how to do that , I am using Intellij

Comment: Side note: I strongly recommend to use at least the Maven project layout (src/main/java, src/main/resources,...) and also consider to use Maven if you're not using it already.

Comment: Place the config folder like this. MyModule-> config->config.properties.

Comment: @KyawBo ...tried didint worked

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

**1. read-only properties**

Use this approach if these are some internal properties the user should not be able to modify. This might also include default values for properties the user should be able to modify.

Package these properties files in the JAR (with Maven usually at some location under src/main/resources) and access them using something like `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`

**2. properties the user should be able to configure after deployment**

When you package your application you have to package these configuration files along with the JAR files. So the files will most likely **not be in a "src" directory** anymore. You probably have to find out where your main JAR is located to create an absolute path to the deployed configuration file.
With Maven you can use the [copy-resources goal of the Maven Resources Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) to generate the proper layout in your main project and e.g. the Maven Assmbly Plugin to package the application.

Comment: in respect to option2 I am accessing from class file in classes folder so the path - ../../config/confog.properties should have worked....but it dont .....  ya i will be changing the format of project structure ..tx ... i m using ant though....

Comment: Yeah, relative paths probably won't work in all scenarios. If I remember correctly the relative path is relative to your current working directory, which might change depending on how you start your application. In the IDE the current directory is likely the project root directory, so you would have to use "src/config/config.properties". But of course this won't work once your application is deployed. See my updated answer.